# Как запретить скролинг на чистом CSS

Tags: css

Вот всплывающее окно, нужно чтобы при его появлении пользователь не мог прокручивать ленту контента до того как закроет его.

```css
body{height:10000px;}
div{
 width:500px;
 height:400px;
 background:gray;
 position:fixed;
 top:90px;
 left:30%;
 display:none;
}
#q1:target, #q1:target+div{
 display:block;
}
#q1{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
 background-color: rgba(000,000,000,.1);
 display:none;
 cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="#q1">Открыть окно</a>

<a href="#x" id="q1"></a>
<div>
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
<p>Элемент</p>
<a href="#x">Закрыть окно</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Добавить `overflow:  hidden;` в CSS. Если только вертикальная/горизонтальная, то `overflow-y:  hidden;` или `overflow-x:  hidden;`.

Comment: К какому селектору?